# how to add ' selected="selected" ' to a option form by getting the value from a url

Tags: jquery

I have the following url

`search.php?card=Xcel&cat=1`

and the following in my search form

```
    <div class="icard" > 
      <select name="card" id="card">
        <option value="Xplore">Xplore card</option>
        <option value="Xpand">Xpand card</option>
        <option value="Xcel">Xcel card</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="icat" >
      <select name="cat" id="cat">
        <option value="1">Health</option>
        <option value="3">Fitness</option>
        <option value="2">Travel & Leisure</option>
        <option value="4">Wellness & Spa</option>
        <option value="5">Security & Techology</option>
        <option value="6">Others</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Using jquery, based on the value in the url

`?card=Xcel`

, i would like to add `selected ="selected"` to the 3rd option, so it is now becomes `<option value="Xcel" selected ="selected">Xcel card</option>`

I have tried the following without any success

```
var val = location.href.match(/[?&]card=(.*?)[$&]/)[1];  
$('#card').val(val);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You need not use selected="selected" it can be done simply like <option value="Xcel" selected>Xcel Card</option>

Comment: you checked what is values of "val" using alert(val) ?

Comment: Do you have to do this in javascript? I`m asking because you have a php file, and you could do this directly using php?

Answer (score 1):

You can get query value with this function in a right way, `location.href.match` may be mistaken:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

And get `card` value:

```
var query = getParameterByName('card');
```

Then check if `query` equal to options:

```
$('#card').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == query){
alert('its equal to query');
  }
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spxonsza/2/)**

**OR** check option equal to query:

```
$("#card option").each(function(){
  if ($(this).val() == query) {
    $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
  }
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spxonsza/1/)**

**OR**

```
$('#card option[value="'+query+'"]').attr('selected','selected');
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spxonsza/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to get selected option passed in the url:

```
<script>
    function findvalue(key) {
        key = key.replace(/[*+?^$.\[\]{}()|\\\/]/g, "\\$&"); // escape RegEx meta chars
        var match = location.search.match(new RegExp("[?&]" + key + "=([^&]+)(&|$)"));
        return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    $("#card option[value='" + findvalue("card") + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
    $("#cat option[value='" + findvalue("cat") + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```js
var q = "?card=Xcel";

var val = q.match(/card=([^']+)/)[1];


$("#card").val(val)

$("#card [value='" + val +"']").attr('selected', 'selected')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icard" > 
      <select name="card" id="card">
        <option value="Xplore">Xplore card</option>
        <option value="Xpand">Xpand card</option>
        <option value="Xcel">Xcel card</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="icat" >
      <select name="cat" id="cat">
        <option value="1">Health</option>
        <option value="3">Fitness</option>
        <option value="2">Travel & Leisure</option>
        <option value="4">Wellness & Spa</option>
        <option value="5">Security & Techology</option>
        <option value="6">Others</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```